# .change not working on a date field in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a date field that I am trying to run a function on to show additional fields if the date entered is changed. The function works fine in Google Chrome, but does not seem to be working at all in IE.

I can't even get the IE console to run a console.log after a change has been made, but again it works fine in Chrome. 
On page load I make sure to check the browser and if in IE I make the field a datepicker because the date data type is not supported.

```
$("#EndDate").change(function dateChanges(){
    console.log("good");
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing the function name. function dateChanges() { => function() {

Comment: @WilliamGates, that would just change the function from being a named function to an anonymous one, it wouldn't affect it being called

Comment: well does the date picker fire a change event? What datepicker do you use?

Comment: Check if the datepicker has an option to call a function when the user selects a date. E.g. jQuery UI Datepicker has `onSelect:`.

Comment: This is what I use when the page loads.                                                if ( $('#EndDate').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
 $('#EndDate').datepicker; }

Comment: @Patrick Evans right but I have seen IE do weird things with named function expressions in the past myself. Given the question being related to IE not working I just wanted to throw out that suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work my modifying how I call the datepicker and by converting date formats.

Datepicker:

```
if ( $('#EndDate').prop('type') != 'date' ) {
    $('#EndDate').datepicker({
    onSelect: function date () { 
    $(this).change();
}
     }).on("change", function() {
        //console.log('working');
});
      };
```

Change function:

```
    $("#EndDate").change(function dateChanges(){
        var endd=document.getElementById('EndDate').value;
        var outputs = endd.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})/, "$3-$1-$2");
        if (outputs !== myDate){
           //do stuff here
}
    });
```